# Would I be able to restore my GUI wallet using the .keys file using a different OS?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, windows, keys-file

I created my GUI wallet months ago on windows 10; I've never had issues accessing it until last night. I have the password in a password manager, as well as written down, I know it's correct. Regardless of this, I keep getting "Couldn't open wallet: Invalid Password." I never wrote down the secret keys, and I can't seem to find the 25 word seed I wrote down. I do have the password and I do have the .keys file, would I be able to restore the wallet using this, but on a different OS? From what I've found while searching, this password issue seems to be tied to windows 10.

Thank you, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as the encryption and decryption algorithm are the same used.

Here are a few tips in case you have problems accessing your wallet:

- check if it's the right wallet and not your donation one or other ones (usually different .keys files)
- check if the password is written in the correct case and you didn't misspelled it
- I suggest you to download the latest version of the software, as it might just be a bug in the software you're using